# Node js : Need to iterate over total rows in excel sheet to insert data into msssql

Tags: node.js, promise, callback

I am working in nodejs and have to read each row in excel and insert the data found there into tables. I am trying to iterate over rows but am unable to do so due to asynchronous nature.

I wish to iterate the below code on a for loop that contains total columns present in the excel sheet.

```
getStoneData(data, function (err, rst) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        cb(err);  // call callback with error
    }

    sql.close();
    sql.connect(config, err => {
        fetchLastID()
            .then(insertFirstStoneData)
            .then(fetchInsertedID)
            .then(insertAllDataFromID)
            .then(lastMethod);
    })
}
```

Only the first data gets inserted.

Comment: What would be wrong with exporting your Excel data as CSV, and then loading it directly into your SQL database?

Comment: Hi , thanks for replying . The problem is i need to read every row , do operations on that data and insert it into different mssql tables for total number of rows present. If i put a for loop for the above code the value of i increments even before all the operations have been performed. So i need a work around for that .Iam quite new to node js